# How to return different datatype in same array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

In C#, i have a return type `string[] array`.

I have two different data types: `string` and `DateTime`.

Is there anyway to return different data types in the same array?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Yes you can just do `object[]` but why do you want to?

Comment: send data from wcs to Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class with those datatypes and return a collection of that class type.

```
public class MyClass {
   public string name;
   public DateTime date:
}
```

return a **`List<MyClass>`**

Comment: Other solution could be to declare the list as object[] and make a convertion